# groovy bug? -- creating an initialized float array?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm using Groovy 1.8.3 (in Grails 2.0).   I need to declare some float arrays, and am using the standard java syntax, e.g.:

```
 float rentVal[] = {1.37f, 1.69f, 2.07f, 2.53f}
```

The compiler errors on this, saying:  expecting '}', found '='

Perhaps because it's late night (pacific time) I'm confusing something here.  My question is what's the right way to do this in Groovy.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tried this in GroovyConsole:

```
groovy> def rentVal = [1.37f, 1.69f, 2.07f, 2.53f] as float[] 
groovy> rentVal.class 

Result: class [F
```

EDIT, it's enough to do this:

```
float[] a = [1.0f, 2.3f, 3.4f]
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this in GroovyConsole. What result did you get?

Comment: Thanks much, I made a typo, what you gave did work.  An additional question: is it a bug that Groovy doesn't allow for the standard Java syntax here?

Comment: Also, you have to remember arrays in Groovy are really Lists. To cast them to primitive arrays, you have to use the `as` operator.

Comment: Thanks much Socha for the reference and also the explanation.  I had thought Groovy was a pure superset of Java (syntax), but apparently this is not the case -- i.e. you can't use Java syntax in all cases.

Comment: @socha23 Arrays aren't Lists, `String[] a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]` is perfectly valid groovy and will give you an array of `String`.  It's just Groovy will give you lists unless you specifically ask for an Array